# OpenRefine sample extension, Butterfly error

Tags: sample, openrefine

I'm trying to make the "sample extension" work in OpenRefine, but when going to localhost:3333/extension/sample/ ,I get this specifc error:

> HTTP ERROR 500 Butterfly Error Butterfly caught the following error
> while processing the request: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError:
> TypeError: Cannot call property stringArrayLength in object
> [JavaPackage com.google.refine.sampleExtension.SampleUtil]. It is not
> a function, it is "object".

I've figured out that it's because of the following line of code in the controller.js file:

```
context.someInt = Packages.com.google.refine.sampleExtension.SampleUtil.stringArrayLength(context.someList);
```

Is there something I'm missing to just get this example extension to work?
Any help would be appreciated!

Kind Regards, Mario

Comment: You can contact OpenRefine developer community directly on the following mailing list https://groups.google.com/g/openrefine-dev You may find there a better audience to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I've posted a message there.